# Android View elements below ListView

Tags: android, listview, layout

I realize that there are a few other posts surrounding this issue but none that seem to address my problem. Essentially I have a navigation drawer with a relative layout that encapsulates the standard listview. Within this relative layout are two listviews, one who's size and contents change dynamically via a CursorLoader and a custom CursorAdapter, and another who's elements are fixed. The reason I designed it this way was I wasn't able to figure out a good simple way to get section headers into the listview. Note the drawer layout file I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/dark_gray_opaque_20"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/western_purple"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_wide" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_modules"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/drawer_logo"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/western_purple"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_customize"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/drawer_modules"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/drawer_your_western"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_personal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/drawer_customize"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/western_purple"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This all worked fine for a few items but when the listview became larger than the screen all contents below the first listview were no longer displayed. Can anyone provide any guidance? Or suggest alternative ways to get section headings into a listview using a custom adapter, provider and cursorloader without placing the headings themselves into the database?

Comment: Would putting your 2 lists into a LinearLayout rather than RelativeLayout and using weightSum and layout_weight get you a little closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately not as it won't be possible to calculate the weights without having an idea of the height of the first listview.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of how you want it to work to better visualise these "section headers"? There are plenty of examples of section header listViews in Android floating around the web, someone might be able to point you in the right direction with a couple of screenshots demonstrating your intended functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make your top ListView's height wrap_content, constrain it to some value in dp, otherwise it will grow as large as it can.

Comment: The height is variable depending on the number of items at the current time. I would like to display the textview and second listview directly after all of the first listviews contents.

Comment: you can use getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener to get the dimensions of all the views you're using and then change them to heights that work. stacking listviews can be tricky business because of the varying child sizes.

Comment: Thanks I will mark this as accepted for the original solution as I am agreeing that stacking listviews is not the correct approach. It seems to me that there is no real way to add headings when using a cursoradapter object and calling bindView unless the headings themselves are in the datasource.